# Remove the first word in a Python string?

Tags: python, string

What's the quickest/cleanest way to remove the first word of a string? I know I can use `split` and then iterate on the array to get my string. But I'm pretty sure it's not the nicest way to do it.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I think the best way is to split, but limit it to only one split by providing [`maxsplit`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) parameter:

```
>>> s = 'word1 word2 word3'
>>> s.split(' ', 1)
['word1', 'word2 word3']
>>> s.split(' ', 1)[1]
'word2 word3'
```

Comment: he wants to remove the first word from the string so the command should be `a = a.split(' ', 1)[1]`

Comment: How can this be modified to be bounds safe?

Comment: much cleaner than my attempt at doing this: 
`' '.join(s.split()[1:])`

Answer (score 23):

A naive solution would be:

```
text = "funny cheese shop"
print text.partition(' ')[2] # cheese shop
```

However, that won't work in the following (admittedly contrived) example:

```
text = "Hi,nice people"
print text.partition(' ')[2] # people
```

To handle this, you're going to need regular expressions:

```
import re
print re.sub(r'^\W*\w+\W*', '', text)
```

More generally, it's impossible to answer a question involving "word" without knowing which natural language we're talking about. How many words is "J'ai"? How about "中华人民共和国"?

Answer (score 3):

The other answer will raise an exception if your string only has one word, which I presume is not what you want.

One way to do this instead is to use the `str.partition` function.

```
>>> s = "foo bar baz"
>>> first, _, rest = s.partition(" ")
>>> rest or first
'bar baz'

>>> s = "foo"
>>> first, _, rest = s.partition(" ")
>>> rest or first
'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you can guarantee the words are separated by a single space, [`str.partition()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) is what you are looking for.

```
>>> test = "word1 word2 word3"
>>> test.partition(" ")
('word1', ' ', 'word2 word3')
```

The third item in the tuple is the part you want.